# How to make a Virtual Keyboard in Java for other programs?

Tags: java, keyboard, jbutton

I want to make something like a virtual keyboard for touchscreen ultrabooks in Java. For example, I want to type in Microsoft Word with my virtual keyboard.

What I've done so far is use `JButton` to represent keys, and use the `Robot` class to simulate computer input.

The problem I have is when I press the `JButton`, it focuses the `JButton`, and therefore the `Robot` class directs the input to the `JButton` instead of the program I want to input to, such as Microsoft Word.

My code looks like this for the button A

```
int KeyValue = KeyEvent.VK_A;
Robot robot ...

JButtton.addMouseListener(new MouseListener(){
    ...
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e){
        robot.keyPress(KeyValue);
    }
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e){
        robot.keyRelease(KeyValue);
    }
    ...
}
...
```

I have confirmed that the button is being pressed. I added a `KeyListener` to the `JButton`, and an "A" is being pressed whenever I click the button, but it's directed at the `JButton` instead of the other program.

I have tried using `JButton.setFocusable(false)`, but it didn't work...

I have searched other questions similar to mine, but they are all typing natively into another Java Window or Textbox, and not another program.

So my question is - How can I make a virtual keyboard that types into other programs? Preferably using `JButtons` but I'm open to any suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried setting the JFrame property of `setFocusableWindowState(false);`? Not sure if button clicks would be registered still.

Comment: I previously only used `setFocusable(false)` and it didn't work, so I just attempted your method and it worked perfectly. Thanks~ If you want post the solution as an answer.

@NESPowerGlove

Comment: Nice. Will post, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the `JFrame` property of `setFocusableWindowState(false);`.